# Proof of the unicity of an interpolation polynomial

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to understand the proof of the following theorem:

*Let $n+1$ points $(x_0,y_0), (x_1, y_1), ..., (x_n, y_n)$ where the $x_i$'s are distinct. Then there exists a unique polynomial $p_n$ of degree $≤ n$, called an interpolation polynomial, such that $p_n(x_i) = y_i$ for $i=0,...,n$.*

The proof is organised in $2$ parts:

Existence

Uniqueness

I understood the existence part but I'm having trouble understanding thoroughly the uniqueness part.

It goes like this:

Let $p_n, q_n$ be interpolation polynomials of degree $≤ n$.

Let $d_n(x) = p_n(x)-q_n(x) \in \mathbb{P}_n$

$d_n(x_i) = P_n(x_i)-q_n(x_i) = 0$$  \forall i = 0,...,n$

But we know that $d_n$ can have at most $n$ roots.

Therefore $p(x) = q(x)$

**Here is my issue**:

I understand that $d_n(x_i) = 0$ And therefore $p_n(x_i) = q_n(x_i)$ for $i = 0,....,n$ But I don't understand why they are equal everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Consider the polynomial $P_n-Q_n$

Its  degree is $\leq n$ and has $n+1$ roots ?.

the only polynomial with this property is zero.